# what is the default order and direction of operation?

Tags: arithmetic, fractions, gre-exam

I have a division like this

> 16/8/4/2

what is the default way to do calculations when the bracket is not specified .

**Method 1 :**

Is it correct to go from right to left like

> [16/ (8 / { 4 / 2 } )]

I tried it in [calculator](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=calculator&oq=cal&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0j69i57j69i59j0l2.920j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=94&ie=UTF-8) as 16/8/4/2 and it gave 0.25

**Method 2 :**

May be it went from left to right

> [({16 / 8} / 4 ) / 2]

Why I am asking this is because I saw a problem in GRE book
like

> ab/c/cd/a

without any brackets .
their solutions reads

**Method 3 :**

$$ (\frac{ab}{c} \times \frac{a}{cd} ) $$
$$ = \frac{a^2 \times b}{c^2 \times d} $$

I am puzzled how they assumed brackets like that without any indication in question .

what is the right way to go as per maths .

Attaching image to show the exact problem . (to show the bars even look of the same size)
[image]

Comment: But here is no problem. They ask for $\frac{\frac{ab}{c}}{\frac{cd}{a}}$, and **not** for $ab/c/cd/a$.

Comment: they are the same .. what if it is slanting dash or horizontal dash .. they all are of same size anyway .. so it is ab/c/cd/a

Comment: No, it is not the same. They write it already as a fraction $\frac{A}{B}$ with $A=\frac{ab}{c}$ and  $B=\frac{c}{cd}$, which determines the bracketing.

Comment: how can we say that if there are no brackets ?

Answer (score 1):

From the image I would say they mean
$$
ab/c\big/cd/a=\frac{\frac{ab}{c}}{\frac{cd}{a}}=\frac{ab}{c}\frac{a}{cd}=\frac{a^2b}{c^2d}.
$$
But you are right, without brackets we have several possibilities, e.g., $16/8$ divided by $4/2$ is $1$.

Comment: e.g., 16/8 divided by 4/2 is 1. . I thinks this is what you have followed in your solution . it is not left to right I think .. you assumed a bracket in between ..

Comment: if you are confident it is from left can you solve the variable problem with brackets step by step and show ... pls ..

Comment: Yes, I assumed a bracket in the middle; sometimes the $/$ is a bit bigger there.

Comment: In the problem every bar looked similar ...

Comment: attaching an image of the problem statement .